# jQuery UI dialog onClick event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i'm trying to open a dialog box with an onclick command, but i'm having no luck whatsoever. I've tried everything and I just can get it to work.

Here the dialog jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function runDialog(){
            $('#testimonialOpen').dialog({
                autoOpen:false
                });
            })
    </script>
```

There is a div id'd testimonialOpen so I know it's selecting the element, and the dialog box works when the autoOpen is removed, however, when I try and call the function like this:

```
<p class="topper">Top words<a onClick="runDialog()"><img id="readMore" style="display: inline; padding-left:40px;" src="../images/content/readMore.png"/></a></p>
```

It just does nothing. I tried to use the 'open' command in the jQuery but it still does nothing, any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly your document.ready handler isn't quite using the right syntax - you're currently placing a function declaration within a jQuery object.

Secondly if you're using jQuery you should use it to attach your events, rather than the outdated `onclick` attributes. The latter should be avoided where possible in preference of unobtrusive event handlers. In jQuery this would be done by using `on()`, and in native JS it would be `addEventListener()`.

Try this:

```html
<p class="topper">
  Top words
  <a href="#">
    <img id="readMore" style="display: inline; padding-left: 40px;" src="../images/content/readMore.png"/>
  </a>
</p>
```

```javascript
$(function() {
  $('#testimonialOpen').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $(".topper a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#testimonialOpen').dialog('open');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this code

```js
 $(function() {
  $("#ok_link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
    });

  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:160,
      modal: true,
      minWidth: 400,
      autoOpen:false,
      buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
          location.href="index.html";
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
 font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<a href="index.html" id="ok_link">OK</a>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Are you sure to go home?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>You are about to redirect to home page. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanations?